# SQL Server : sum two rows and create one row and after wards delete duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Empid   OrgID    UniqueRowID   YearMonth      s      e       seOrg
1517    754     201802-1517-754 201802       0,81   0,81    0,49
1517    754     201802-1517-754 201802        1        1    0,39
```

I want above duplicate row to one row sum(s)/2, sum(e)/2,sum(seorg)/s

```
 1517   754     201802-1517-754 201802        .905   .905       .88
```

need above row and delete  two duplicate after calculating single row

Comment: Empid I OrgID I UniqueRowID I YearMonth  I  s   I   e        I   seOrg  =>Columns

Comment: 1517 754 201802-1517-754 201802 0,81 0,81 0,49  =>Row1 data

Comment: 1517 754 201802-1517-754 201802 1 1 0,39 => Row2 Data

Comment: `sum(seorg)/s` doesn't produce your result, do you mean `sum(seorg)/max(s)` ..?

Comment: @Yasirayub . . . Do you want to change the table or just get the particular results?

Comment: No I dont want to change table , these two records need to delete after updating with  avg row i.e i need single row in table for this month for this employee its big table but i am getting merge error because of these two rows

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a two steps process using common table expressions.
The first step is selecting the avgs and sums in a cte and update the table,
and the second step is deleting duplicates using row_number:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  Empid, OrgID, UniqueRowID, YearMonth,
                AVG(s) As avgS,
                AVG(e) As avgE,
                SUM(seOrg)  As sumSeOrg
        FROM TableName
        GROUP BY Empid, OrgID, UniqueRowID, YearMonth
    )

    UPDATE T
    SET s = avgS,
        e = avgE,
        seOrg = sumSeOrg
    FROM TableName T
    JOIN CTE 
        ON T.Empid = CTE.Empid
        AND T.OrgID = CTE.OrgID
        AND T.UniqueRowID = CTE.UniqueRowID 
        AND T.YearMonth = CTE.YearMonth;

    WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  Empid, OrgID, UniqueRowID, YearMonth,
                -- order by is not important since all duplicates now have the same values
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Empid, OrgID, UniqueRowID, YearMonth ORDER BY @@SPID) As RN
        FROM TableName
    )

    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use avg and sum as :

```
select Empid, OrgId, UniqueRowId, YearMonth, 
       avg(s) as s,avg(e) as e,sum(seOrg) as seorg
  from tab
group by Empid, OrgId, UniqueRowId, YearMonth;
```

Comment: merge two rows but numeric columns divide by two  later delete both rows and just keep new row that has merged

Comment: @Yasirayub what if there are more than two rows. `avg` works for all cases.

Comment: this will return avg ok fine , but need to delete two rows afterwards and keep only this average row

Comment: @Yasirayub you may try CTAS format  `create table tab2 as select <the above query I wrote>` to keep resulting rows in a new table.